# Simple steps to deploy and test portlet in Liferay

Tags: java, deployment, liferay, portlet

I would appreciate if someone could give few easy steps how to deploy and test portlet in Liferay portal. I tried to search of course but some of the tutorials doesn't apply to new versions, some were overcomplicated and some didn't work for me.

I have a one JSR-286 portlet which I want deploy (I have Tomcat bundle on 6.1 version), add it to same page and see if the portlet works. So if you can can give five steps or so how to do this I would be really grateful.

P.S. This seems to me like in the Boromir meme - *one does not simply deploy portlet into Liferay:-)*

Comment: +1 for the Boromir meme reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)Run the ant deploy script

2).Log in to the
    portal with your default administrator credentials

3). On any page,
    click Add in the Dockbar and select More

4). By default, the portlet
    you just created would be under the Sample category. Click the Add
    button next to whatever portlet you just deployed

Good luck let me know if you have any questions

Comment: 1) What ant script?I prefer manual deployment, is placing portlet into tomcat/webapps equivalent?

Comment: place the war file into deploy. I think you also could place the directory in webapps, but I've never done it that way.

Comment: did you try creating the WAR and dropping that in tomcat deploy?

Comment: does it compile if you try to compile it? I tried manually deploying by dropping the WAR in tomcat, and I waited until Tomcat told me it was ready for use. And it worked so I'm not sure what specifically is going on for you. The directions I gave in my answer are straight from the Liferay Developer Training book

Comment: I tried it again and still nothing, I just can't see the portlet under samples. It works in GateIn and it's taken from Portlets in Action book so I believe this should be ok:)Btw, portlet is based on Spring Portlet MVC if that matters...

Comment: Ok, I made that work, I removed liferay specfic settings and that was probably causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deploy portlets in liferay is hot deployment.

Check this link.. Surely it will work

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/4.2/official/liferay-portlet-development-guide-4.2/multipage/ch04.html